# Fraction length

Tags: math, fractions

How to get the fraction length? If at all possible, without using string operation or loop

```
should all return length of 3:
5.234
5.23400
5.234000
```

Any programming language is accepted

[EDIT]

Not a homework, I want to display fractions at its minimum.  Example, I defined numeric(18,8) in database.  If the user entered only 5.234, the data saved in database is 5.23400000.  I just want to display it back as 5.234 only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If Int(num) = num Then Return 0
num *= 10
If Int(num) = num Then Return 1
num *= 10
If Int(num) = num Then Return 2
num *= 10
If Int(num) = num Then Return 3
num *= 10
If Int(num) = num Then Return 4
num *= 10
If Int(num) = num Then Return 5
num *= 10
If Int(num) = num Then Return 6
num *= 10
If Int(num) = num Then Return 7
num *= 10
If Int(num) = num Then Return 8
Throw New Exception("Number exceeds expected precision")
```

No string operations, no loops.

**EDIT:**

BTW, to do this with a loop:

```
result = 0
Do While (Int(num) !> num) 
    num *= 10
    result += 1
Loop
Return result
```

Slightly more elegant

Comment: This one is good.  I'm about to settle on repeated dividing(I give up the idea of loop-less) solution and counting 'til 0, but cannot do it since fraction is what I am after, not the whole number.  This is a good logic!

Answer (score 3):

Given that you're concerned about display and not internal representation, why not just strip the trailing 0s?

```
#!/use/bin/perl

my @nums = ( '5.234', '5.23400', '5.234000' );
$_ =~ s/0+$// for @nums;  # remove trailing 0s
$_ =~ s/\.$// for @nums;  # remove trailing .

print "@nums\n";
```

You can probably optimize both into a single regex.

Comment: In fact 5.234 can NOT be represented in IEEE 745's 64 bit integer, it would actually be approximated by 5.233999999999999985789145284797996282577514648437500 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For the non-fraction part, the length is:

```
int((ln(v)/ln(10))+.999)
```

as long as v > 1 where ln() is the natural logarithm and int() always rounds down. For v == 1, ln(v) returns 0, so you must handle this in a special case.

It ought to be possible to achieve the same thing for the fraction part (`v - int(v)`) but my math fails me.

Comment: I doubt that anything to do with natural log might be of value. Because String.format("%x", Double.doubleToRawLongBits(5.234)) yields 4014ef9db22d0e56 and this,preserving all digits, evaluates to 5.2339999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375 whereas 5.25 can be represented exactly. 5.251 again is approximated by 5.25100000000000033395508580724708735942840576171875. My point being the length is not monotonic in the case of fraction.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement the division algorithm.
And you stop when the number count > 7 or 8 digits (for float32)

Answer (score 0):

When using Java and JDBC, get the value via [ResultSet.getBigDecimal()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBigDecimal(int)). To get the correct scale, use this code (Java 5 and up; there is a bug in Java 1.4 which makes it fail for "0.0"):

```
int precision = v.stripTrailingZeros().scale();
```

For Java 1.4, see [this page](http://forums-beta.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=769584&messageID=4385828).

Answer (score 0):

In Java:

```
Double.valueOf("5.34000").toString();
```

I assume, you may want to convert the string to double anyway.