# How to get the length of a numbers fraction part?

Tags: java, numbers, fractions

How do I find out the length or the number of digits of the fraction part of a decimal number?

I can see a few aproaches, e.g. with Strings like this one:

```
public static int getNumberOfFractionDigits(Number number) {
    Double fractionPart = number.doubleValue() - number.longValue();
    return fractionPart.toString().length() - 2;
}
```

But what is the best way to determine the length?

I could imagine some problems if I use Strings, e.g. because the locale and number format may be different from system to system. Is there a nice way to calculate it? Maybe without iteration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you do with things like 1/3?

Comment: I need this for validation. There is no 1/3 possible in the database! I found my question is a duplicat to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585237/fraction-length

Comment: the accepted answer is bad there...

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you can get overflow with `longValue()` and rounding error with the subtraction which can make it look like there is more digits than there would be. e.g. 1.1 - (long) 1.1 = 0.10000000000000009

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a simple method for this, hope it can help someone.

```
public static int getFractionDigitsCount(double d) {
    if (d >= 1) { //we only need the fraction digits
        d = d - (long) d;
    }
    if (d == 0) { //nothing to count
        return 0;
    }
    d *= 10; //shifts 1 digit to left
    int count = 1;
    while (d - (long) d != 0) { //keeps shifting until there are no more fractions
        d *= 10;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: It's buggy. Won't work for many numbers, like 111.1. You cannot d == 0. When you 111.1 - 111 -> it gives 0.099999 and not 0.1 as you would intuitively expect!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static int getNumberOfFractionDigits(Number number) {
 if( number == null ) return 0; //or throw
 if( number.doubleValue() == 0.0d ) return 0;
 BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(number.toString()); 
 //BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(number.doubleValue()); // if double precision is ok, just note that you should use BigDecimal.valueOf(double) rather than new BigDecimal(double) due to precision bugs in the latter
 bd = bd.stripTrailingZeros(); //convert 1.00 to 1 -> scale will now be 0, except for 0.0 where this doesn't work
 return bd.scale();
}
```

Edit:

If the number is actually an iteger (i.e. fraction of 0) this would still return 1. Thus you might check whether there actually is a fractional part first.

Edit2:

`stripTrailingZeros()` seems to do the trick, except for 0.0d. Updated the code accordingly.

Comment: this idea is ok baring the fact BigDecimal has no `BigDecimal.valueof(java.lang.Number)` method and if it happens to NaN/Infinity it'd suck big time, it'd suck even more if you try a round number... like `BigDecimal.valueOf(1000d).scale()`

Comment: Could you provide a link? As far as I know, you there's no MathContext involved in the code above.

Comment: Well, technically you can use `number.toString()` but I'd not recommend it, Double.toString() already applies rounding on its right own and working w/ BigDecimal you want to control the rounding yourself. Extra note: the code will not work for negative values (and you do not need to test 0.0 if you are going to `stripTrailingZeros`)

Comment: No, you have to test 0.0 since `stripTrailingZeros` will return a scale of 1 (at least in Java 5). Additionally, `new BigDecimal(double)` is discouraged (read the JavaDoc) and `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)` will do a `Double.toString(double)` anyways. And why wouldn't it work for negative values?

Comment: *And why wouldn't it work for negative values?* My bad, for round numbers like 1000,  `System.out.println(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(1000d)).stripTrailingZeros().scale());` is -3. Negative 3; really bad expression, sorry. (I tried to mention it in the 1st comment)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, as well as the NaN check that's missing :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use java.text.NumberFormat.

```
nf = java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance (); 
// without BigDecimal, you will reach the limit far before 100  
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits (100);
String s = nf.format (number.doubleValue ())
```

You may set the Decimal-Identifier as you like, and use regular expressions to cut off the leading part, and String.length () to evaluate the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like many offered the Big Decimal. It's easy on the eyes at least.
The code shall work for ya.

```
package t1;

import java.math.*;

public class ScaleZ {
    private static final int MAX_PRECISION = 10;
    private static final MathContext mc = new MathContext(MAX_PRECISION, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
    public static int getScale(double v){
        if (v!=v || v == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY || v == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)
            return 0;//throw exception or return any other stuff

        BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(v, mc);
        return Math.max(0, d.stripTrailingZeros().scale());
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test(0.0);
        test(1000d);
        test(1d/3);
        test(Math.PI);
        test(1.244e7);
        test(1e11);
    }

    private static void test(double d) {
        System.out.printf("%20s digits %d%n", d, getScale(d));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not use `new BigDecimal(double)` instead use `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)`. Excerpt from the JavaDoc: "The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable and its use is generally not recommended;  see the notes under the BigDecimal(double) constructor."

Comment: Ehh, nice try. read the code again, mostly b/c there is no use of `new BigDecimal(double)` :) it's `new BigDecimal(double, MathContext)`

Comment: The problem you have is that you will get up to 54 decimal places with "new BigDecimal(double)" when you might only get 1 with toString(). e.g. 0.1

Comment: @Peter, yes but there is MathContext afterwards, so it does not happen, if you convert double to string 1st you round it already, so the MathContext is exactly for the reason.

Comment: so 1 + 1e-11 would return 0 ? ;)  The problem with dealing with floating point numbers is you get rounding error.  The only safe way to deal with rounding error is to know how many digits of accuracy you expect.  It is not possible to know the number of digits of accuracy from the value which is what the OP appears to be trying to do. The number of digits of accuracy is something you must add based on the context of your application.  Here you have chosen 10 digits which may be right for most uses, but is arbitrary without more information.

Comment: @Peter, you can't possibly have fixed number digits for a floating point. It's obvious some number cannot be represent, so it has to be rounded 1st. The OP mentions database and there the representation is usually fixed point, not floating. I left it a constant, but of course it can be dynamic, the idea is just to illustrate the case. However if a number is already a `double` it has lost it's fixed point properties and the only way to return 'em is rounding.

Comment: @bestsss please read the JavaDoc of `new BigDecimal(double, MathContext)`, that's where I got the excerpt from, so this applies there as well :)

Comment: @Thomas, I know you did, but it makes no sense... since if you go for String.valueOf(d) the result is to be rounded 1st (String.valueOf(double) does rounding) and then applied MathContext which is pointless.

Comment: Yes, but FreakShow actually didn't ask for rounding, so using a MathContext to artificially restrict the number of digits seems to be counter intuitive :)

Answer (score 0):

That was my best implementation:

```
public class NumberHandler {

    private static NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);

    static {
        formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        formatter.setGroupingUsed(false);
    }

    public static int getFractionLength(double doubleNumber) {
        String numberStr = formatter.format(doubleNumber);
        int dotIndex = numberStr.indexOf(".");
        if (dotIndex < 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return numberStr.length() - (dotIndex + 1);
        }
    }

}
```

Not effective, probably not perfect, but the other options was worse.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static int getNumberOfFractionDigits(double d) {
    String s = Double.toString(d), afterDecimal="";
    afterDecimal = s.subString(s.indexOf(".") + 1, s.length() - 1);
    return afterDecimal.length();
}
```

Comment: no need to assign a String, just to call `length()`. The code has off-by-1 mistake (s.length()-1) and doesn't work for science notions like 1.1e19

Comment: I believe any number ending in `.0` would return 1.

Comment: 1) typo: subString -> substring 
2) unit test fails: for 5.75, it returns 1, but the expected value is 2