# How do I Convert double or float (all digits) to int?

Tags: c++, floating-point

How do I Convert double or float (all digits)  to int?

Eg if I have a double 0.9332, the function will return 9332,
1.32001 will return 132001

Comment: You can't. Most all floating point numbers are an infinite series of numbers in base 10 format. This comes up in various forms almost every day. Just search on floating point.

Comment: Hard to do because it is very difficult to figure out where a floating point number "ends". They are not precise, 10, for example, could be 9.99999999999999. They also decay into nonsense after a a number of digits (7 for a `float`, 15 for a `double`)

Comment: @user4581301. Not all floating point numbers have repeating, fractional representations. For instance 3,2,.5,.25,.125, .375 are exact in IEEE floating point. But most are not. Even simple numbers like .1

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Would it be possible if the double were to be normalized first to say 5 digits?

Comment: @doug True, but I wanted a simple example. as it is 10 is easily representable as a `float` or a `double`.

Comment: @ChrisMcmonagle: Then you can just mutiply with `10 power 5` and assign to an `int`

Comment: i think you should convert it to string and remove point from string, then convert it to int. but it is non-returnable

Comment: If the numbers are all 1 >x > -1, you can multiply by 10 to the power of 5 and cast to an integer. If you need to round, check if the sixth digit is >= 5.

Comment: Presuming you mean `64-bit` int (e.g. `long long`) you would have to ensure the number fell within `std::numeric_limits<long long>::min() <= double <=  std::numeric_limits<long long>::max()`

Comment: Ok that gives me something to work with. I will try counting the digits, evaluating the sixth number and also the string theory. Thanks!

Comment: You may have up to what... a thousand and then some digits when extracting all decimal digits from a double faithfully. Do you really want that?

Comment: @doug: Every binary floating-point number is exactly representable with a finite number of decimal digits.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, good point. Incorrectly worded. It's most base 10 fractionals (per my example) that require an infinite number of bits in the mantissa. Hence can't be represented in IEEE binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this will work ! question is similar to this one :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314954/how-to-get-the-length-of-a-numbers-fraction-part

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int getFractionDigitsCount(float );
int main()
{
    float a=1.9332;
    int p = getFractionDigitsCount(a);
    cout<<"answer is : "<< a * pow(10,p);

    return 0;
}
 int getFractionDigitsCount(float d) {
    if (d >= 1) { //we only need the fraction digits
        d = d - (long) d;
    }
    if (d == 0) { //nothing to count
        return 0;
    }
    d *= 10; //shifts 1 digit to left
    int count = 1;
    while (d - (long) d != 0) { //keeps shifting until there are no more fractions
        d *= 10;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: i compiled it and program is running fine , and the question doesn't mention to handle the -ve values.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more thought, you cannot gracefully handle the *direct conversion* of `double` (or `float`) to integer by simple casts and multiplication due to the limitation of floating-point numbers not exactly representing all values leading to repeating decimal points, etc.. that causes the multiplication of the fractional-part approach to fail for numbers like `9.999999`.

However, you can use an intervening `string` and parsing the digits from the string to avoid all of the pitfalls. (either by converting the number to a `stringstream` if the floating-point number is already within your program, or by simply reading the floating-point value as a `string` to begin with.

Then it is simply a matter of handling the cases for a negative value or values beginning with leading zeros (e.g. `-31.3333`) and then copying (`.push_back()`) the digits from the original floating-point value to an intermediate string before calling your conversion to either `.stoi(), .stol(), or .stoll()`. You can use the `try {...} catch {...}` exception handling to handle any failed conversion.

For your function returning a `long long` value, you could do something like:

```
#define LONGDIGITS 19

long long sdigits (std::string s)
{
    int start = 0;                          /* flag skip leading 0 */
    size_t n = 0, maxdigits = LONGDIGITS;   /* set max digits */
    long long l = 0;                        /* int to hold conversion */
    std::string result;                     /* string to hold digits */

    if (s[0] == '-') {              /* if leading '-' */
        result.push_back ('-');     /* save for sign */
        maxdigits++;                /* increment max by 1 */
    }
    for (auto c : s) {              /* loop over all chars */
        if (isdigit (c)) {          /* if not digit skip */
            if (c != '0')           /* if not 0, the set start flag */
                start = 1;
            if (start) {                /* if start set */
                result.push_back (c);   /* add digit to result */
                n++;                    /* increment digit count */
            }
        }
        if (n == maxdigits)         /* if digit count == max */
            break;                  /* break */
    }
    try {                           /* try conversion to long long */
        l = std::stoll (result);
    }
    catch ( std::exception& e ) {   /* catch/handle exception */
        std::cerr << "error: std::" << e.what() << " out_of_range.\n";
    }

    return l;   /* return long long value, or 0 on error */
}
```

Putting it together in a short example, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <cctype>

#define LONGDIGITS 19

long long sdigits (std::string s)
{
    int start = 0;                          /* flag skip leading 0 */
    size_t n = 0, maxdigits = LONGDIGITS;   /* set max digits */
    long long l = 0;                        /* int to hold conversion */
    std::string result;                     /* string to hold digits */

    if (s[0] == '-') {              /* if leading '-' */
        result.push_back ('-');     /* save for sign */
        maxdigits++;                /* increment max by 1 */
    }
    for (auto c : s) {              /* loop over all chars */
        if (isdigit (c)) {          /* if not digit skip */
            if (c != '0')           /* if not 0, the set start flag */
                start = 1;
            if (start) {                /* if start set */
                result.push_back (c);   /* add digit to result */
                n++;                    /* increment digit count */
            }
        }
        if (n == maxdigits)         /* if digit count == max */
            break;                  /* break */
    }
    try {                           /* try conversion to long long */
        l = std::stoll (result);
    }
    catch ( std::exception& e ) {   /* catch/handle exception */
        std::cerr << "error: std::" << e.what() << " out_of_range.\n";
    }

    return l;   /* return long long value, or 0 on error */
}

int main (void) {

    std::string s;
    long long l;

    std::cout << "enter double in range of 64-bit int: ";
    if (!(std::cin >> s)) {
        std::cerr << "err: invalid input.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    l = sdigits (s);

    std::cout << s << " -> " << l << '\n';
}
```

There are probably a number of ways to do this, so don't take this as the only approach, but you can accurately handle the conversions and validate so you identify any failures.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/double_all_digits
enter double in range of 64-bit int: 0.9332
0.9332 -> 9332

$ ./bin/double_all_digits
enter double in range of 64-bit int: 1.32001
1.32001 -> 132001
```

Negative values are handled properly as well:

```
$ ./bin/double_all_digits
enter double in range of 64-bit int: -0.9332
-0.9332 -> -9332
```

By using a string for intermediate parsing, you avoid the floating-point repeating decimal issue:

```
$ ./bin/double_all_digits
enter double in range of 64-bit int: 9.999999
9.999999 -> 9999999

$ ./bin/double_all_digits
enter double in range of 64-bit int: -31.3333
-31.3333 -> -313333
```

By using the `try {...} catch {...}` exception handling you can catch any `out_of_range` conversions. The largest allowable conversion to `long long` would be:

```
$ ./bin/double_all_digits
enter double in range of 64-bit int: 0.9223372036854775807
0.9223372036854775807 -> 9223372036854775807
```

While adding one would result in a value out of range for `long long`:

```
$./bin/double_all_digits
enter double in range of 64-bit int: 0.9223372036854775808
error: std::stoll out_of_range.
0.9223372036854775808 -> 0
```

Comment: Your first paragraph is wrong. You can extract all decimal digits from binary floating point numbers. There just may be a bit too many (to be practical) of them for the exact value.

Comment: Sure, you can extract them all, that was meant to say you can't *directly* convert them without running into the fractional-part problems. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Take care of the integral part, remove/subtract it. Until the rest is 0, multiply by 10, take care of the integral part, remove/subtract it... What problems do you see here? There aren't any. No rounding or truncation.

Comment: The problem happens with numbers such as `9.9999` where the floating-point representation is not exactly `99999 / 10000`. When you attempt a *cast - subtract real-part, multiply fractional part by 10, repeat* -- you end up repeating more than 4 times. With numbers like `0.9332` it is trivial and it works, with `9.999999` you are out of luck.

Comment: You don't really have 9.9999. The exact number is slightly different. You have the exact number whose digits you can recover all (there will be more than five).

Comment: Yes, exactly, that was the problem the OP was trying to avoid.

Comment: Shouldn't be using binary then to begin with.

Comment: I do get what you are saying -- it boils down to what you want. (and I agree) I you have a representation of `9.9999` and want `99999` then you run into the more than 5-digits. If you just want whatever the floating point digits end up being -- then it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use C++ standard library string function to convert float digit to integer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int floatDigitToInt(float num) {
    std::string str_f = std::to_string(num);
    // here one can check NaN, inf etc..
    std::string str_i;
    for (int i = 0; i < str_f.length(); ++i) {
        if (std::isdigit(str_f[i])) {
            str_i += str_f[i];
        }
    }
    return std::stoi(str_i);
}

int main() {
    float num_f = 1.32001;
    std::cout << floatDigitToInt(num_f);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have needlessly painted yourself into a corner. If you need your results in proper decimal floating point, you should use decimal floating point like [dec64](http://dec64.com/) for your calculations instead of trying to hack the botched result back into normalcy.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I Convert double or float (all digits) to int?

```
0.9332  --> 9332  
1.32001 --> 132001
```

Goal not strictly possible in general.
[Typically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), there are about 2<sup>64</sup> different `double`.  `0.9332` and `1.32001` are not in that set of `double`.

---

Let us look at the closest alternatives.

The closest `double` have *exact* values more like the below.  Some `double`, as *binary* floating point values need 100s of *decimal* digits to represent exactly.

```
0.933200000000000029487523534...
1.32000999999999990563992469...
```

To reasonable print those values "to int", we need to select what precision is desired.

Say we choose a fixed number of digits after the decimal point.  (Not really a great idea for small `double` values as they all become "0"`), code could post-process the string as desired.

```
int len = snprintf(NULL, n, "%.*f", 16, double_value);
char buf(len + 1];
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.*f", 16, double_value);
char *dp = strchr(buf, '.');  // Look for the decimal point - might be `,` in some locales
if (dp) {
  size_t len = strlen(dp + 1);
  memmove(dp, dp + 1, len + 1); // shove over fraction
  while (len > 0 && dp[len - 1] == '0') {
    dp[--len] = '\0';  // lop off trailing zeros.
  }
}
```

Now `buf[]` contains only digits (unless infinity/NaN) suitable for `strto...()` conversion to some integer type - if it "fits".  `buf[]` could contain hundred of digits as `DBL_MAX` is often about 3.0e308 or so.  OP's goal is not expressed for very large/small `double`.

---

For a limited range of `double`, code code use use `"%.*g"` which "trailing zeros are removed from the fractional portion of the result" and then post=proess the string to remove the `'.'`.

```
printf("%.16g\n", 0.9332);
printf("%.16g\n", 1.32001);
```

Output

```
0.9332
1.32001
```